# how to deal with devices don't support vertex array object

Tags: vao

I have fallen into a marsh dealig with mobiles don't support vao,the only solution i can think of is using if else whenever draw, like this

```
if(vao is supported)
{
    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    glDraw..........;
}
else
{
    glBindBuffer(....);
    glVertexAttribPointer(.....);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(.....);
    glDraw..........;
}
```

But it's tedious and inefficient, is there better way? thx